# OTA update is not enter into recovery mode in android10

Tags: recovery-mode, ota-update, aosp

Created ota_v1.zip and ota_v2.zip.

Followed this script https://github.com/dpavlin/android-command-line/blob/master/adb-install-update.sh

My device not going recovery more, just device is reboot. I could not able to understand where did mistake.

I am trying understand , How to install OTA.zip file into my target device.

Thanks in advance. Refered https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/ab also.

Comment: Not clear which process you are following to create OTA update zip files (though it's development related). It looks you have a recent device with Android 10. Also the given reference is about OTA updates on A/B devices. And on A/B devices there is no recovery partition and hence no recovery mode. OTA updates take place on inactive slot while device is running.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @IrfanLatif. created ota.zip through(make otapackage -j8) command. I am trying understand How to do OTA update in Android 10 device.I have done posted experiment but not worked.